# How to retrieve an array from Oracle stored procedure with Java JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

In my Oracle database i have type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DOSSIER_RESULT AS OBJECT
(
  id           number,
  user_id      number
)
```

Also a collection of this objects

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DOSSIER_RESULTS_ARRAY AS TABLE OF DOSSIER_RESULT
```

Also a procedure that has OUT param of the last type

```
 procedure get_dossier(i_search_mode           in number,
                        i_person_id             in number,
                        i_case_num              in varchar2,
                        i_auto_num              in varchar2,
                        o_dossier_results_array out dossier_results_array)
```

In java code i have

```
public static void getDossierTest(Dossier obj) {

        LOGGER.info("------obj: " + obj);

        Connection conn = null;
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            conn = DbConnection.getConnection(DbConnection.CONN_SU);
            Map map = conn.getTypeMap();
            map.put("DOSSIER_RESULT", Class.forName("data.DossierSearchResultsModel"));
            conn.setTypeMap(map);

            callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{call pkg_1av_test.get_dossier(?,?,?,?,?)}");

            callableStatement.setInt(1, 1);
            callableStatement.setLong(2, obj.getId() == null ? 0 : obj.getId());
            callableStatement.setString(3, obj.getNum() == null ? "" : obj.getNum());
            callableStatement.setString(4, obj.getGrnz() == null ? "" : obj.getGrnz());
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);

            callableStatement.execute();

            Array array = callableStatement.getArray(5);

            for (Object item : (Object[]) array.getArray()) {
                if (item instanceof DossierSearchResultsModel) {
                    LOGGER.info("------------Got that: " + item.toString());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
```

But in the

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-03115: An unsupported network data type or data representation
```

Please, help! What am i doing wrong?
I need to get that array (or collection ) from Oracle stored procedure in java code

And the model class

```
package data;

import java.sql.SQLData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLInput;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;

public class DossierSearchResultsModel implements SQLData {

    private Long id;
    private Long original_id;
    private Long parent_id;
    private Integer av_system_id;
    private Integer is_active;
    private String title;
    private Integer org_id;
    private String org_code;
    private Integer card_type;
    private Long user_id;


    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("--------getSQLTypeName");
        return "DOSSIER_RESULT";
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {

    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {

        System.out.println("-----writeSQL");
        stream.writeLong(getId());
        stream.writeLong(getOriginal_id());
        stream.writeLong(getParent_id());
        stream.writeInt(getAv_system_id());
        stream.writeInt(getIs_active());
        stream.writeString(getTitle());
        stream.writeInt(getOrg_id());
        stream.writeString(getOrg_code());
        stream.writeInt(getCard_type());
        stream.writeLong(getUser_id());
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getOriginal_id() {
        return original_id;
    }

    public void setOriginal_id(Long original_id) {
        this.original_id = original_id;
    }

    public Long getParent_id() {
        return parent_id;
    }

    public void setParent_id(Long parent_id) {
        this.parent_id = parent_id;
    }

    public Integer getAv_system_id() {
        return av_system_id;
    }

    public void setAv_system_id(Integer av_system_id) {
        this.av_system_id = av_system_id;
    }

    public Integer getIs_active() {
        return is_active;
    }

    public void setIs_active(Integer is_active) {
        this.is_active = is_active;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Integer getOrg_id() {
        return org_id;
    }

    public void setOrg_id(Integer org_id) {
        this.org_id = org_id;
    }

    public String getOrg_code() {
        return org_code;
    }

    public void setOrg_code(String org_code) {
        this.org_code = org_code;
    }

    public Integer getCard_type() {
        return card_type;
    }

    public void setCard_type(Integer card_type) {
        this.card_type = card_type;
    }

    public Long getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(Long user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DossierSearchResultsModel{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", original_id=" + original_id +
                ", parent_id=" + parent_id +
                ", av_system_id=" + av_system_id +
                ", is_active=" + is_active +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", org_id=" + org_id +
                ", org_code='" + org_code + '\'' +
                ", card_type=" + card_type +
                ", user_id=" + user_id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: try to add in `registerOutParameter`  third argument with a typename `DOSSIER_RESULTS_ARRAY`

Comment: Common practice, when working with java/c# and you need to get data from oracle SP, use cursors. What you basically do in your procedure, you open the cursor with simple SQL search query and return it trough out parameter as SYS_REFCURSOR type. Keep it simple.